# Importing SQL in phpmyadmin error

Tags: php, html, css, phpmyadmin, xampp

Very newbie here about databasing. I copied a POS system to my friend and I want to study it's function how it works stuff like that.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIlk2.png)

Comment: It is very simple, You need to select database. Put this in your sql file `use database_name;`

Comment: Hahaha all good now thank youuu.

Comment: If you think that above comment is solution then please mark accept my below answer

Answer (score 1):

First click the database in which you want to import your data, then click import and the data should be imported correctly. If there is no database, then create one.

Answer (score 0):

Error (which is showing in the attached image) means you need to select the database. For example if you want to create table

```
/*Table structure for table `collection` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `collection`;

CREATE TABLE `risetogether_image` (
   ....
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The above code will return same error because in  above we didn;t select any database.

So you need to select database like below

```
USE `your_database_name`;

/*Table structure for table `collection` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `collection`;

CREATE TABLE `risetogether_image` (
   ....
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to Create Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBmje.jpg)

Enter database name and click on Create Button, then after Execute your SQL Query.